# Finding the congruence matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, elementary-number-theory

Consider the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ over the field $\mathbb{Q}$ of rationals. Which of the following matrices are of the form $P^{t}AP$ for a suitable $2\times2$ invertible matrix $P$? $$1.\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&-2\end{bmatrix}2.\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix} 3. \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix} 4. \begin{bmatrix}3&4\\4&5\end{bmatrix}$$
Cleary $2$ is not possible, because congruent matrices have same inertia, that is they have same number of positive, negative and zero eigenvalues. How to check other options?

Comment: For 1, we have
$$
\pmatrix{2&0\\0&-2} = \pmatrix{1&1\\1&-1}^T\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}\pmatrix{1&1\\1&-1}
$$

Comment: For 3, we can argue that no rational $P$ will do: since $\pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}$ is the diagonalized form of $A$, the columns of $P$ would have to be an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors, by the spectral theorem.  However, any such basis uses irrational entries

Comment: This is a duplicate of [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3264963) that was posted nine hours ago.

Comment: For 4, I suspect that no rational $P$ will work. In particular, we find that
$$
P = \frac 1{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{1&1\\3&5}
$$
works, and I believe that we can argue that the matrix $P$ that accomplishes this is unique in some sense

Comment: @user1551 I'm not sure what the procedure is in these situations; the question you linked doesn't have an answer either so I don't know if it makes sense to close this as a duplicate

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I don't know either, but I would encourage anyone who wants to answer one of them to answer the earlier question.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: that question has 4 close votes. This question might be viewed to have more context or it might not. In any case, that question will not be answerable once closed.

Answer (score 2):

It's not difficult to show that follows

Let $U=\begin{pmatrix}u&v\\v&w\end{pmatrix}\in M_2(\mathbb{Q})$.

Then $A,U$ are congruent matrices over $\mathbb{Q}$ iff $v^2-uw$ is in the form $\dfrac{p^2}{q^2}$ where $(p,q)\in (\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\})^2$.

Begin with the case $uw\not= 0$...