# Which of the following matrices are of the form $P^tAP$ for a suitable $2\times 2$ invertible matrix $P$ over $\mathbb Q$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0& 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ over the field $\mathbb Q$ of rationals.Which of the following matrices are of the form $P^tAP$ for a suitable $2\times 2$ invertible matrix $P$ over $\mathbb Q$?

1. $\begin{pmatrix} 2& 0 \\ 0 & -2\end{pmatrix}$
2. $\begin{pmatrix} 2& 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}$
3. $\begin{pmatrix} 1& 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$
4. $\begin{pmatrix} 3& 4 \\ 4 & 5\end{pmatrix}$

My Try:-

Characteristic equation of $A$ is $\lambda^2-1=0.$ So, Distinct Eigen values. So, It is diagonalizable. Hence there is an invertible $P$ such that $P^tAP=\begin{pmatrix} 1& 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}.$ It was a question appeared in CSIR Exam. I get less than 5 minutes to solve this problem. I can take $P=\begin{pmatrix} a& b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$ and Solve $P^tAP=\begin{pmatrix} 3& 4 \\ 4 & 5\end{pmatrix}$, $P^tAP=\begin{pmatrix} 2& 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}$ and $P^tAP=\begin{pmatrix} 2& 0 \\ 0 & -2\end{pmatrix}.$ But it is time consuming. Can you suggest some theory behind solving this?

Comment: I've seen this exact problem on the site before; I'm trying to find it

Comment: @Omnomnomnom you mean [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3347951/which-of-these-matrices-are-of-the-form-ptap-from-csir2019?rq=1)? it is in the related list

Comment: @Azlif Well spotted but no, I specifically remember answering the question myself.

Comment: @Truth_searcher that's the one, thanks. I guess I didn't put an answer together after all.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Sir, I asked for a shortcut.

Comment: I also found https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3265452/finding-the-congruence-matrices

Comment: But it is for $\mathbb Q$. Is there any generalized condition?

Comment: I am not able to ask in the comment. I want to know. Is there any generalized version for his answer over $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: @Truth_searcher If that's what you were looking for in the beginning, it would have been helpful if you included a link to the question in your problem statement.

Comment: @Truth_searcher his version **is** an answer over $\Bbb Q$, so I don't understand exactly what you're asking for

Comment: Actually, it seems that the answer he gives is incorrect since his condition incorrectly implies that choice 3 is congruent to $A$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom What if the question is replace $\mathbb Q$ to $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @Truth_searcher then by [Sylvester's law of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia), you only need to check the sign of the determinant.

Answer (score 1):

A is a diagonalisable matrix with distinct eigenvalues. So the matrix which can be written as P^tAP have also diagonalisable having distinct eigenvalues. See that only option (2) does not have distinct eigenvalues. Hence answer will be rest others.